# Animation partly works but not completely

Tags: animation, css

At the moment I have [this](http://jsfiddle.net/AndyMP/Xkee9/1/), a small DIV that slides in from the top to the center of a container DIV when the mouse hovers over the container DIV; but on mouseout, it slides back out to where it came from. What I'd like to do is have the DIV slide out of the other side of the DIV, directly opposite where it entered.

Is this possible using just CSS? (I imagine with JQuery it would be more straightforward)

```
<div class="blocks">
    <div class="blocks_title">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="blocks">
    <div class="blocks_title">
    </div>
</div>

.blocks {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    margin: 20px;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border: 1px dotted #333;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.blocks_title {
    position: relative;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    top: 0px;
    left: 40px;
    background: #333;
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: all .25s;
       -moz-transition: all .25s;
            transition: all .25s;
}

.blocks:hover .blocks_title {
    top: 40px;
    opacity: 1;
}
```

Comment: So you don't want jQuery/JavaScript?

Comment: I'm confident I could do it with JQuery, but would love to see if somebody could finish this off with just CSS.

Comment: Interesting one, at first glance no but I'm trying to think whether or not something could be done with a cunningly crafted background image to create the illusion of it moving down - but I'm stumped if I can think of anything, just go with jQuery ;)

Comment: Ok :) I'm not clued up enough with CSS animation to know what can and can't be done. I figured because it almost did what I needed it would be possible.

Comment: I don't think that's possible with css,  but I'll do my best to find a solution, just because I also like the thought of doing everything with css

Comment: I think you 'll need to wait until the :mouseenter and :mouseleave selectors are invented.

Comment: @Puyol I actually tried to imitate that. I failed, of course, refer to my answer with the demo that elaborates my tries.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

And just when everyone is convinced that it's not gonna work with css only:

http://jsfiddle.net/Xkee9/36/

I used an animation for the mouseenter and a transiton for the mouseleave

Edit: added firefox fix

Edit: Explanation:
(I always use -webkit- -prefixes, just to explain it in Chrome and Safari, Firefox uses the -moz- -prefix, opera the -o- - prefix)

When nothing happens:
the block is at the bottom of the div.blocks (`top:80px;`), with an opacity of 0, also there is no animation running

When hovering:
the block moves instantaneous to the top with no transition (see:`-webkit-transition: none;`), because then the animation `down-1` is running. That animation moves the block from `top:0` to `top:40px;` in .25s. After the animation, the block stays at `top:40px;` because that's what I added in `.blocks:hover .blocks_title`.

When mousleaving:
there is no animation running anymore, but the block moves from `top:40px` to `top:80px;` in .25s because of `-webkit-transition: all .25s;`

Comment: Nice, although it only works on Chrome -- doesn't work on Firefox 14.0.1. +1, though.

Comment: Wow, that's amazing. Great job.

Comment: Any chance you can add a few comments to the fiddle explaining what it all does :)

Comment: Just added the explanation ;)